# ElasticSearch - Search without apostrophe

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to allow users to search without entering an apostrophe.

E.G type Johns and still bring up results for John's

I've tried multiple things including adding the stemmer filter but with no luck.

I thought I could potentially do something manual such as

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "char_filter": [{
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\'s",
      "replacement": "$1 $1s $1's "
  }],
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "text": "john's dog jumped"
}
```

And i get the following response

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "john",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "johns",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "john's",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "dog",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "jumped",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

However I still don't get a match when I search for "johns" with out the '

My settings look like:

```
          "analyzer" : {
            "my_custom_search" : {
              "char_filter" : [ "flexible_plurals" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          },
          "char_filter" : {
            "flexible_plurals" : {
              "pattern" : """\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\'s""",
              "type" : "pattern_replace",
              "replacement" : " $1 $1s $1's "
            }
          }
```

My mappings like

```
                "search-terms" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer" : "my_custom_search"
                }
```

I am using the match query to query the data

Comment: can you share your index setting, mapping and search query to confirm what i've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: can you find the difference, I am using the exact same configuration and as shown in my answer, it returns result for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct, Hope you are using the `match` query and you have defined your field as `text` with the custom analyzer, if you use the `text` field without your custom analyzer which uses your `char_filter` it will simply use the `standard` analyzer and won't generate the `johns` token hence no match.

### Complete Working example

**Index setting and mapping**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "char_filter": {
                    "apostrophe_filter": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\'s",
                        "replacement": "$1 $1s $1's "
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "custom_analyzer": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "char_filter": [
                            "apostrophe_filter"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample document**

```
{
   "title" : "john's"
   
}
```

And search for `johns`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "johns"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72937076",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "john's" --> note `john's`
                }
            }
        ]
```